# AMF3 decoder in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

How can i decode AMF3 Object in Flex. We have a python Socket server which encodes data as AMF3.

We already deserialize data in Android Client but cant find a good way to do that in Flex.

#### Edit.

Take a look how we are doing Java for Android client.

```
String res = res.substring(1);
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(res.getBytes()); 
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
AMF3Deserializer amf = new AMF3Deserializer(dis);
Object o = null;

try { 
    o = amf.readObject(); 
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} 

Map map = (HashMap)o;

Object[] ob = (Object[]) map.get("result_set"); 
Object[] obn = (Object[]) ob[0];
```

Comment: @Slomojo, Thanks for editing How did you do that, I just joined today.

Comment: On SO, You earn X amount of Rep by answering questions, marking questions as answered, etc, and gain privileges, I can edit questions and answers, for example.

Comment: You need 2000 reputation to edit other people's posts . More info in the Stack Overflow FAQ, including how to gain reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq I would have expected you'd be able to edit your own question, though.  There is an edit link on the left under your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ByteArray.readObject() will decode AMF.

Comment: thanks for your answer I did try every way within my skills, Can you give me any example?
you can see how i am doing with java.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on how you're making the request, but you should be able to get a ByteArray result, and then so long as the Python code is encoding things correctly, simply call myByteArray.readObject() and it'll do all the work for you. You might have to call registerClassAlias() first, just so Player knows which class to instantiate. Check the AS3 docs for registerClassAlias() and ByteArray on adobe.com

Answer (score 2):

incase there are new searchers for this topic, 
in AS3, use `flash.net.Socket.readObject()` method. It will automaticaly read the object as AMF format

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RemoteObject` to connect to a AMF service.

Read [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_4.html) for more info.

Comment: Our Connection is not through any AMF channel, Thanks for your post.

Comment: ??! Your question states that you encode data as AMF3 ... you'll need to clarify the details of your question. AMF is the Adobe 'native' data communication format, so Flex handles it very easily.

Comment: Yes if you are connected by RemoteObject then it is easy to handle, I guess, but we are connecting to our server by Socket class from net package and AMF3 serialized object come from server So i cant use RemoteObject.

Comment: Oh I see, well, at that point you have no built in support for deserializing AMF, however, rather than writing a deserializer, I'd suggest you review the rationale for doing the comms this way, since whatever you are doing via the socket, you could be doing far less painfully via remoting proper.

Comment: Not if you get hold of it via a socket connect, there's no ByteArray (AMF) -> object decoder, that I know of, there's no demand for one, since you'd usually get those streams via remoting.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you use a [RemoteObject](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/data_access_4.html) to make your calls to the server?  Then deserialization is handled automatically for you.

Did you write your own AMF serialization / deserialization methods on the server?  Or did you use something like [PythonAMF](http://www.pyamf.org/index.html)?

Comment: Yes we are writing our own serialization, take a look how we are doing Java for Android client.
  
String res = res.substring(1);
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(res.getBytes());
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
AMF3Deserializer amf = new AMF3Deserializer(dis);
Object o = null;
  
try {
      o = amf.readObject();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
  
Map map = (HashMap)o;
Object[] ob  = (Object[]) map.get("result_set");
Object[] obn = (Object[]) ob[0];

Comment: @Smin - avoid putting `code` in comments, no one will bother to read it.

Comment: Yes i know but how did you format the code? Do you have suggestion?

Comment: You can just select the code sample and press `Ctrl+K` - (make sure there is a blank line above / below. (only in questions and answers.)

Comment: @Smin Rana I'm not sure where to send you for an answer.  It sounds like you'll need to write your own AS3 deserializer / serializer.  I'm sure one exists in the Flash Player, but there is no documentation I'm aware of that will let you access it.